# Le français est-il la langue la plus rapide?

Tags: prononciation, comparaison-de-langues

Quand j'étais gosse, je m'amusais avec mes amis à mimer les touristes qu'on rencontrait et à faire semblant de parler des langues étrangères. Quand il s'agissait du français, je me rappelle bien qu'on accélérait le rythme des phrases...

Est-il vrai que les Français sont le peuple qui parle le plus vite au monde ?

Comment: Ce genre d'impression doit probablement varier culturellement. Pour beaucoup de français, c'est l'italien qui donne parfois cette impression de *mitraillette verbale*, qui ressort très souvent dans les représentations caricaturales...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Il y a deux facteurs qui entrent en jeu pour définir la vitesse d'une langue.

- La vitesse avec laquelle les syllabes sont énoncées influence la perception qu'on peut avoir de la vitesse de cette langue. Ce facteur est déterminant lorsqu'on ne comprend pas ce qui est dit. Plus les syllabes s'égrènent vite, plus les locuteurs semblent parler rapidement. Ce nombre s'appelle le **débit syllabique**.
- Mais, par ailleurs, le nombre de syllabes qu'il faut pour exprimer une idée varie suivant les langues. S'il faut plus de syllabes pour la même idée, la langue est de fait plus lente. Ce nombre s'appelle la **densité syllabique d'information**.

Le temps qu'il faut pour énoncer une idée (le **débit d'information**) est le produit de ces deux nombres.

Il existe une recherche universitaire sur ce sujet, et notamment une étude assez connue de chercheurs du CNRS Lyon. Cette étude portait sur 7 langues (japonais, mandarin, espagnol, italien, français, anglais, allemand). Elle a permis de constater que certaines langues comme le japonais ou l'espagnol nécessitent beaucoup de syllabes, mais ces syllabes sont prononcées très vite — ce qui est permis par la relative simplicité des syllabes (en japonais, notamment, une syllabe est formée d'une consonne suivie d'une voyelle suivie optionnellement d'un `n` — pas de consonnes doubles, pas de diphtongues, etc.). D'autres langues, au contraire, comme le chinois et l'anglais, ont des syllabes complexes (large éventail de voyelles et de diphtongues en anglais, accent tonal en chinois), mais ont besoin de peu de syllabes pour exprimer une idée. Ainsi le japonais et l'espagnol ont un fort débit syllabique, mais une faible densité syllabique d'information. Au contraire, le chinois et l'anglais ont une forte densité syllabique d'information mais un faible débit syllabique.

Au final, le débit d'information varie assez peu entre les langues : plus une langue a des syllabes complexes, et plus chaque syllabe porte d'information, mais plus il faut de temps pour la prononcer, ce qui compense.

Par rapport aux langues étudiées, le français est plutôt dans la moyenne (aussi bien en termes de densité syllabique d'information que de débit syllabique). Ainsi le français n'est ni particulièrement rapide ni particulièrement lent.

#### Références

- François Pellegrino, Christophe Coupé and Egidio Marsico. [“A cross-language perspective on speech information rate”](http://www.ddl.ish-lyon.cnrs.fr/fulltext/pellegrino/Pellegrino_to%20appear_Language.pdf). *Language*, 2011.
- Article de vulgarisation [dans *Pour la Science*](http://www.pourlascience.fr/ewb_pages/a/article-les-langues-du-monde-un-meme-debit-d-information-30410.php), aussi [mis en ligne](http://www.ddl.ish-lyon.cnrs.fr/fulltext/Christophe/Pellegrino_2012_PLS_paper.pdf) par les auteurs.
- Un [résumé en français](http://www.thetranslationpeople.fr/blog/langues/parlent-a-toute-vitesse/)
- Un [article en anglais](http://content.time.com/time/health/article/0,8599,2091477,00.html)
- Un [article en français](http://www.altissia.com/blog/fr/qui-parle-le-plus-rapidement-l-anglais-ou-l-espagnol/) avec un poster en anglais
- Une [question sur le sujet](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/612/why-does-speech-speed-seem-to-vary-between-different-languages) sur le site Linguistics Stack Exchange

Comment: (+1) Merci et bravo, c'est lumineux. Merci aussi à jihed gasmi pour cette question que je m'étais toujours posée sans avoir pensé à la formuler ici.

Comment: Aussi comme jihed gasmi, j'ai toujours pensé que le Français est une langue plus rápide que la majorité. Je dois dire : je suis allé au Quebec recentement et j'ai eu l'impression que ils parlent beaucoup plus lente que les français. Quand j'étais la-bas, je pouvais comprendre beaucoup de choses que ils disaient. Mais quand je suis en France, je ne comprends presque rien parce que (je pense) les Français parlent plus rapide que les sympa quebecois. J'ai lu la réponse de Gilles (mais non les articles) +++

Comment: +++ et je pense encore que le français en general peut être une langue aussi vite que la moyenne quand un Belge ou un Quebecois parle, mais quand un français parle, oh dear, c'est rápide.

Comment: @cldjr Il y a aussi des différences entre locuteurs d'une même langue. Souvent les gens plus éduqués parlent plus vite. Les Parisiens ont la réputation de tout faire plus vite, y compris parler, mais je ne sais pas si c'est vrai toutes choses égales par ailleurs. Je ne connais pas d'étude à ce sujet.

Comment: Je confirme que ça dépend du locuteur. J’ai connu un natif français qui parlait vraiment très vite. Même si je suis moi-même français je devais m’accrocher pour suivre… Sinon je crois pouvoir dire que les espagnols parlent également assez vite.